# When a triplet of scalar fields ($[a_x \: a_y \: a_z]$) can represent a vector field?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

I can't understand when an *assigned* triplet of scalar fields $$[a_x \: a_y \: a_z](x,y,z)$$ can represent a vector field $$\overline{a(x,y,z)}$$
There are some requirements for the triplet of *scalar fields*, in order for them to be the **components** of a *vector field*?

## Edit 1: What my professor said

A triplet of scalar fields $\textbf{a}=(a_x\: a_y \: a_z)$ represents the scalar components of a **vectorial** field only if, given the versor $$\hat{\textbf{n}}=n_x\hat{\textbf{i}}+n_y\hat{\textbf{j}}+n_z\hat{\textbf{k}}$$
the scalar component of $\textbf{a}$ in the *direction* of $\hat{\textbf{n}}$ is $$a_n=n_xa_x+n_ya_y+n_za_z$$

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My initial instinct is "always", but if you have a context suggesting otherwise, please add that context

Comment: I feel like you're misreading your professor. The statement is that $a_x,a_y,a_z$ being components of a vector field $\vec{a}$ means that $a_x=\hat{i}\cdot \vec{a}$, $a_y=\hat{i}\cdot \vec{a}$, $a_z=\hat{i}\cdot \vec{a}$. The conditions are on $\vec{a}$, not on $a_x,a_y,a_z$. Any triplet of scalar fields is permissible. (Of course, this no longer applies if you want, say, a _conservative_ vector field.)

Comment: Ok, thank you @Semiclassical, but i'm sure that my professor said explicitly that, if we have a triplet of scalar fields $(a_x \: a_y \:a_z)$, then the triplet must satisfy the relationship written, in order for it to be the components of the vector field $\textbf{a}$

Comment: Let me double down: If you pick an arbitrary triplet of functions $A,B,C$, then you can always write down $A\hat{i}+B\hat{j}+C\hat{z}$ as a vector field with those components. There are no restrictions on $A,B,C$ unless you demand something more than "vector field."

Comment: Ok @Semiclassical, i think i have understood. Thank you very much. I will ask my professor clarifications about this.